# Workflow 2010 run successfully but no email sent out

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, send-email

I am using SharePoint workflow 2010 to send an email after an item is created in the list. The status is completed but no email received. Kindly advise.

[image]

Comment: Can you please detail exactly what your workflow is trying to do (for example, with screenshots)?

Comment: Hi, I added the screenshot of the workflow above

Comment: Can you check if SharePoint is able to send any emails at all? For example can you set an email alert on a list and see if these emails are sent?

Comment: How can I set an email on a list?

Comment: Follow the instructions in this link - https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-an-alert-to-get-notified-when-a-file-or-folder-changes-in-sharepoint-e5a79e7b-a146-46da-a9ef-d65409ba8918

Comment: Can you please also add the screenshot of the configuration of Email action?